# Active Directory Federation Services (ADFS) Web Agent with a ColdFusion based application?

Tags: coldfusion, web-config, single-sign-on, adfs

I'm working on SSO and will be using [Active Directory Federated Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb897402.aspx) (ADFS 2.0) as my means of accomplishing this.  I am acting as the Service Provider (SP) and my application is built on ColdFusion and not .NET.  Is it possible for me to setup the web.config file so that I can bypass the [ADFS web agent](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc783116%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) and just parse the claims with ColdFusion?  I thank you guys in advance for any assistance that you can provide.

Comment: ColdFusion does not normally use web config files.  In fact, I'm not sure if it ever does.

Comment: ADFS 2.0 does not use web agents. That was an ADFS v1.0 feature.

Comment: @DanBracuk, it was my understanding that the web config file was needed to pass off the SAML cookie to the web app.  Not necessary for coldfusion to interpret it.

Comment: @nzpcmad, if ADFS 2.0 doesn't use the web agent, how do I parse the SAML cookie?

Answer (score 0):

Never used ColdFusion but you need some flavour of SAML stack to do this.

Have a look at [SAML Service provider with coldfusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11084193/saml-service-provider-with-coldfusion) which has a link to the original article [SAML, SSO and ColdFusion](http://blog.tagworldwide.com/?p=19).

OR

ADFS 1.0 is the default on Windows Server 2008. You have to download ADFS 2.0 over this. You could go back to ADFS 1.0 and try the web agent path but be aware it's an old product with no upgrade path and very little documentation e.g. on Windows Server 2012, ADFS 2.0 is the default.

**Update:**

Can I just get ADFS 2.0 to point to my web app (Coldfusion) and then just consume/parse the cookie from there?

No - ADFS is a SSO system via Federation. You can logon via WS-Fed or SAML. It then looks in the RP config. for the claims rules and then mints the token with the correct claims, signs it, possible encrypts it and then passes it back. There is no way to get the token without following this procedure.

Comment: so you're saying that I can just get ADFS 2.0 to point to my web app(Coldfusion) and then just consume/parse the cookie from there?

Comment: This is understood. My confusion stemmed from the web.config file and the AD FS web agent and how to get them to interact with coldfusion.  It's good to know that I don't need them.  Just to ensure that I'm understanding correctly, the token that is generated from the AD FS on the Identity Providers(IdP) is passed to my AD FS since I'm the Service Provider(SP).  The AD FS checks for the SAML token and if it's present...it passes this token to the web app and the parses of the claims is done there?  Is this correct?

Comment: Yes - just to note that you could also go direct from your app. to the ADFS IDP.