# ColdFusion: SAML Service Provider ADFS

Tags: service, coldfusion, saml, adfs, cfml

Our company is programming custom webshops for our customers. Now a customer has contacted us to implement the authentication under use of SAML. The customer is running an ADFS server already. My job is it to evaluate how difficult the work is for our company and what steps we need to take.

I searched the web now for quite a long time now and I didn't find really useful stuff. I understand the basic dataflow, but a more ColdFusion specific example for a service provider would be great.

Examples or explanations how we have to do this would be great!

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few links that should get you started. In this case are you the Service Provider or Identity Provider?

http://blog.tagworldwide.com/?p=19

[SAML Service provider with ColdFusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11084193/saml-service-provider-with-coldfusion)

http://dragonsaber.blogspot.com/2009/09/coldfusion-saml-part-1.html

There's another one here on SO that I can't seem to find that is similar to the first link. I also did a presentation at cf.Objective 2013 that was online in their Dropbox but seems to be gone. Guess I'll have to put that up somewhere for everyone.

Comment: We are the service provider. The IdP is already set up by the customer. Thank you very much, i will look through the links you provided. The presentation would be nice i think. Its hard to find CF-Informations on the implementation (im a asp.net developer and it seems there is a lot more stuff that works with asp.net).