# ADFS Authentication implementation for Coldfusion,

Tags: coldfusion

I need to use **ADFS Authentication implementation for Coldfusion**.

I've found only this post, but I'm not sure if this is the right answer...

https://community.adobe.com/t5/coldfusion/i-want-to-implement-adfs-2-0-integration-with-coldfusion-has-anyone-implemented-this-before-please-i/td-p/7361728?page=1

Comment: Please check your links comments. It's having answer itself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ColdFusion: SAML Service Provider ADFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17087082/coldfusion-saml-service-provider-adfs)