# Integrating SSO with Coldfusion applications

Tags: active-directory, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, coldfusion-9

I am trying to integrate single-sign-on using saml with ColdFusion-9 applications. Could any one please suggest me how can i approach this problem as i am new to ColdFusion.

I googled for any possible solutions or anything remotely similar to problem at hand, didn't stumble across any suitable solution.

Regards
Amit

Answer (score 0):

Does this post help? [SAML Service provider with ColdFusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11084193/saml-service-provider-with-coldfusion) As an alternative you could use a Java based solution. Coldfusion CFC's can be used similar to this `createObject("java", "some.java.class");`